# Rails app showing contents of public folder instead of app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, ubuntu-16.04

I am hosting multiple rails app on a single server.

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04LTS,
- Web server: Apache 2.4.18, Passenger 5.0.30.

First I have made a symlink: `/var/www/html/hrm -> /var/www/rails/hrm/public`, and I have this `conf` file:

```
<Location "/hrm">
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
Require all granted
AllowOverride all
PassengerEnabled On
PassengerBaseURI /hrm
PassengerAppRoot /var/www/rails/hrm
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
RailsEnv production
</Location>
<Directory /var/www/rails>
Require all granted
Options -MultiViews
</Directory>
```

`sudo passenger-status` shows passenger is running but NOTHING in "Application groups".  Requesting `http://{server}/hrm` gives the contents of the public folder.

This worked before with Ubuntu 14.04LTS.  I researched stackoverflow.com and added the directives `PassengerAppRoot` and `PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot` which were not required before with Ubuntu 14.04LTS.

What have I missed?

Comment: Have you installed the apache module, and added the "LoadModule passenger_module" directives the installer gives you? Also, in your individual vhost configs, you need PassengerRuby directives.

Comment: These have been done automatically when I installed Passenger.  They are set up in passenger.load and passenger.conf files under /etc/apache2/mods-enabled.

Comment: Try removing PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on